# Load Container and EntityManager within a fixture in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two fixtures, one LoadSport.php and one LoadCategory.php in my Symfony project.

Every instance of sport has a private 'category' attribute which is an instance of Category.
I am trying to retrieve the categories I already in my database and load them in the Sports fixture (I chose some sports). I followed the official using container within fixtures (http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#using-the-container-in-the-fixtures) as suggested in another thread.

So this is my code for the LoadSport.php:

```
class LoadSport implements FixtureInterface, ContainerAwareInterface
{
    private $container;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;  
    }

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $i = 0;
        $em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
        $category = $em->getRepository("MyBundle:Category")->findOneById(1);
        $names = array('SportA', 'SportB', 'SportC');


        foreach($names as $name)
        {
            $sport = new Sport();
            $sport->setName($name);
            $sport->setCategory($category);

            $manager->persist($sport);
        }

        $manager->flush();
    }

    public function getOrder()
    {
        return 2;
    }
```

I tried to call a separate manager to get Category n1, and when I do php app/console doctrine:fixture:load, I get this error message:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
>     Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to MyBundle\Entity\Sport::setCategory()
>     must be an instance of MyBundle\Entity\Category, null given, called in .../MyBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/LoadSport.php on line
>      xx and defined

How can I retrieve the category of id 1. or any other category within my LoadSport.php fixture and set the category of the Sport instance? What am I doing wrong? Why am I getting a null value wheras as it should be a category entity?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you insert the category in the db? Are doctrine fixture also?

Comment: Yes, I insert it as a fixture. 

In order to load categories first, in my LoadCategory.php, I put 

>  public function getOrder()
 {
  return 1;
 }

And in my LoadSport.php, I put

>  public function getOrder()
 {
  return 2;
 }

Comment: @Nadjib - You won't stop getting that error unless you do what I've written below. It is very simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the ObjectManager passed into the load function. Like so:

`$category = $manager->getRepository('MyBundle:Category')->findOneById(1);`

**Update**:

As pointed out below, whilst this approach is nice and simple it can lead to problems when manipulating data in the fixtures. The [Symfony Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#sharing-objects-between-fixtures) details the correct way to do this.

Comment: Hi GM,

Thanks for your answer, but I already tried it and it still displays the same error:


>  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException] Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to MyBundle\Entity\Sport::setCategory() must be an instance of MyBundle\Entity\Category, null given, called in .../MyBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/LoadSport.php on line xx and defined

Do you know other reasons from where the error might come from?

Comment: After having tried it again, it worked. I must have made a mistake somewhere else last time.

Thanks a lot for your help GM, I appreciate.

Comment: This is a "BAD PRACTISE". @Nadjib - You're populating Category with fixtures then you're going to get Category with references - [Sharing Objects between Fixtures](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#sharing-objects-between-fixtures).

Comment: Works the same with Symfony 4
$manager->getRepository(Category::class) ->findOneById(1);